# Restrict access to app using MS Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices, mdm, microsoft-graph-api

We are developing an Android Application using MS Graph API to access Exchange Online Calendar info.

I know several enterprises are strict about how the exchange data is shared and may restrict access for our app using MDM or other exchange controls.

I need to understand what changes IT Administrators could do to block access to an app that uses MS Graph and OAuth2? I need this info so that we can test our setup and be better prepared for it.

Thanks